Virtual Hard Disk prevent overwrite from Google Drive
Since Google Drive for Desktop in Windows doesn't support one-way sync, is there idea that I can tricky that app by revoking permission to overwrite any changes in my local directory that mounted by VHD?
Since it's virtual hard disk, maybe there is option to do that in Windows.


the question is, how to try it?
